# Laravel flatten and pluck from multidimensional collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, hierarchy

I have to retrieve just an array of **id** from the given collection, something like **[10,54,61,21,etc]**.
I've tried *flatten*, *pluck*, but nothing seems to work apart from a *foreach* which is something I would like to remove at this step.

```
// Model
class Children extends Eloquent {
    public function directChildrens(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Children','father_id','id')->select('id','father_id');
    }

    public function childrens(){
        return $this->directChildrens()->with('childrens');
    }
}

// Controller
return $children->childrens()->get();
```

As expected it works fine. Here a result:

```
[{
"id": 10,
"father_id": 2,
"childrens": [
    {
        "id": 54,
        "father_id": 10,
        "childrens": [
            {
                "id": 61,
                "father_id": 54,
                "childrens": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "father_id": 10,
        "childrens": []
    }
]
}]
```

How can I perform a *pluck('id')* of this collection in order to get **[10,54,61,21]** ?

Comment: is there a possibility "the result array" to have more than one element ?

Comment: what do you mean @Ersoy?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/srvidi according to the screenshot is there a possibility to have an another json object/element inside the array ? But i posted an answer, let me know if it works for your case.

Answer (score 7):

```
$result = [
            [
                "id" => 10,
                "father_id" => 2,
                "childrens" => [
                    [
                        "id" => 54,
                        "father_id" => 10,
                        "childrens" => [
                            [
                                "id" => 61,
                                "father_id" => 54,
                                "childrens" => []
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id" => 21,
                        "father_id" => 10,
                        "childrens" => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

```
return collect($result)
        ->map(function ($value) {
            return Arr::dot($value); // converts it to the dot notation version (added the example at the end)
        })
        ->collapse() // collapse them into a single one
        ->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            return $key === 'id' || Str::endsWith($key, '.id'); // filter first id + patterns of .id
        })
        ->values() // discard dot notation keys
        ->toArray();
```

`Arr::dot()` method turned collection into the following format which flattens all into the same level.

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "father_id": 2,
    "childrens.0.id": 54,
    "childrens.0.father_id": 10,
    "childrens.0.childrens.0.id": 61,
    "childrens.0.childrens.0.father_id": 54,
    "childrens.0.childrens.0.childrens": [],
    "childrens.1.id": 21,
    "childrens.1.father_id": 10,
    "childrens.1.childrens": []
  }
]
```

Thanks to @Dan warning about deprecated/removed function `array_dot`. Replaced with `Arr::dot()`

Comment: I suggest using `Illuminate\Support\Arr::dot()` instead of the `array_dot` helper because since Laravel 5.8 these [helpers are deprecated](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26898) and were eventually [removed all together](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27504) in Laravel 5.9.

Comment: Thanks @Dan - didn't know that - i will update it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) only once, I just wraped into a [`pipe` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pipe) to use functional approach used in Eloquent and Collections

```php
return $children->childrens()->get()->pipe(function ($collection) {
    $array = $collection->toArray();
    $ids = [];
    array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$ids) {
        if ($key === 'id') {
            $ids[] = $value;
        };
    });
    return $ids;
});
```

Note that you must convert collection to array and store it in a variable as `array_walk_recursive` first parameter is passed by reference, then the following code would cause fatal error **Only variables should be passed by reference**

```php
array_walk_recursive($collection->toArray(), function (){
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution right here, requires to declare an additional method though:

```php
function extractIds($obj)
{
    $result = [];

    if (isset($obj['id'])) {
        $result[] = $obj['id'];
    }

    if (isset($obj['children'])) {
        return array_merge($result, ...array_map('extractIds', $obj['children']));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The method will securely check for the `id` property as well as the `childrens` property before recursing into it. *(By the way, the word `children` is already the plural form, no need for an additional `s` at the end. So be aware I removed it in my example.)*

Using this, we can utilize a Laravel collection to easily chain the required transformation calls:

```php
$result = collect($array)
    ->map('extractIds')
    ->flatten()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you want `pluck('id')` mean but pluck doesn't works on recursive array. So i use recursive to get the id values.

```php
$result->map(function ($item) {
  $ids = [];
  array_walk_recursive($item['childrens'], function ($item, $key) use(&$ids) {
     if($key === 'id') $ids[] = $item;
  });
  return array_merge([$item['id']], $ids);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flatten() to get an array of [id, father_id, id, father_id, ...].
then you make a filter to get just the values with even indexes:

```
$result = [
            [
                "id" => 10,
                "father_id" => 2,
                "childrens" => [
                    [
                        "id" => 54,
                        "father_id" => 10,
                        "childrens" => [
                            [
                                "id" => 61,
                                "father_id" => 54,
                                "childrens" => []
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "id" => 21,
                        "father_id" => 10,
                        "childrens" => []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];


$collection = collect($result);

$flattened = $collection->flatten()->all();

return array_filter($flattened, function ($input) {return !($input & 1);}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

you can add a check of the first node if it had a father_id (in case of the head of tree), if not, you take the first id and execute this code for children.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive algorithm you may add into your `Children` model:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

public function getAllChildrenIds()
{
    return Collection::make([$this->getKey()])
        ->merge(
            $this->childrens->map->getAllChildrenIds()
        );
}
```

Comment: Plucking `id` can't handle your multi-dimensional example

Comment: So, why you posted that answer? There is nothing form me there, unless you provide a real use of it.

Comment: ` nothing seems to work apart from a foreach` I offered you another way than the `foreach`, which is primarily the goal you want to reach. Accepting it or not is up to you.