# How check if record exist in an unlimited nested children relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, children

I am struggling to come up with a way to query this. I have a model that displays a resource with its children and the children are from the same table itself which means the resource tree is unlimited nesting. the relation is as follows

```
class UserDrive extends Model
{
    public function children(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'folder_id','id')->with('children');
    }
}
```

and my controller calls it like shown below

```
    public function getFolder($folder_id)
    {
        return new UserDriveCollection(UserDrive::with("children")->where('user_id', $this->user)->where('id', $folder_id)->paginate($this->paginatePerPage(), ['*'], 'page', 1));
    }
```

the resource looks like below

```
public function toArray($request)
    {

            return [
                "id" => $this->id,
                "folder_name" => $this->folder_name,
                "children" => self::collection($this->whenLoaded('children'))
            ];

    }
```

and the results are in the following format

```
[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "folder_name": "Setswana Material",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "folder_name": "Love Materials",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 11,
                                "folder_name": "folder54",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 19,
                                        "folder_name": "folder1",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 20,
                                        "folder_name": "folder2",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 21,
                                        "folder_name": "folder",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 22,
                                        "folder_name": "folder3",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 23,
                                        "folder_name": "folder4",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 24,
                                        "folder_name": "folder5",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 12,
                                "folder_name": "folder5",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 13,
                                "folder_name": "\nfolder5",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 14,
                                "folder_name": "folder",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 15,
                                "folder_name": "folder4",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 16,
                                "folder_name": "folder3",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 17,
                                "folder_name": "folder2",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 18,
                                "folder_name": "folder1",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "folder_name": "folder1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "folder_name": "folder2",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "folder_name": "folder3",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "folder_name": "folder4",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "folder_name": "folder5",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "folder_name": "folder2",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "folder_name": "folder3",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "folder_name": "folder4",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
```

so my question is how do I check if a resource exists as a child or as a child of a child or even deeper than that. the relationship/tree array is unlimited so I want to check for all possible children.

so if I want to check if `id: 24` is a child of `id: 1` it should be true as of the data above. and if I want to check if  `id: 2` is a child of `id: 1` if should be true as well but if I check `id: 5` is a child of `id: 1` it should be false because it is not a child under it.

Comment: I've done something similar with a recursive function to "flatten"(https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten) `children()`'s `id` values into a Collection, then simply doing `$flattenedCollection->contains($id)`, but I think you'll need some kind of recursive method to step through the tree until there are no more Children (or children of children, etc.) to check, or the element is found (break condition).

Comment: thanks for leading me in the right direction. I found a solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62248472/11998509).

Answer (score 0):

for those who may want to do something similar. this is was my solution to the problem.

sample data   `covert to php array`

```
[
            {
                "id": 1,
                "folder_name": "Setswana Material",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "folder_name": "Love Materials",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 11,
                                "folder_name": "folder54",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 19,
                                        "folder_name": "folder1",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 20,
                                        "folder_name": "folder2",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 21,
                                        "folder_name": "folder",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 22,
                                        "folder_name": "folder3",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 23,
                                        "folder_name": "folder4",
                                        "children": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 24,
                                        "folder_name": "folder5",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 12,
                                "folder_name": "folder5",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 13,
                                "folder_name": "\nfolder5",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 14,
                                "folder_name": "folder",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 15,
                                "folder_name": "folder4",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 16,
                                "folder_name": "folder3",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 17,
                                "folder_name": "folder2",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 18,
                                "folder_name": "folder1",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "folder_name": "folder1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "folder_name": "folder2",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "folder_name": "folder3",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "folder_name": "folder4",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "folder_name": "folder5",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "folder_name": "folder2",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "folder_name": "folder3",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "folder_name": "folder4",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
```

and the code to get ids from the code

```
        return $resource->pipe(function ($collection) {
            $array = $collection->toArray();
            $ids = [];
            array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$ids) {
                if ($key === 'id') {
                    $ids[] = $value;
                };
            });
            return $ids;
        });
```

they results are in the following format

```
        [
            2,11,19,20,21,22,23,24,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
        ]
```

it gets all the `id:` fields from the multidimentional array and I tested for depth of up to 8 steps deep in, it is able to get all the `id:`

Comment: But that **doesn't** answer the question of one `id` being a child of the other. It **only** retrieves all "ids" in the whole tree.

Comment: for my use case getting the IDs is still good enough. maybe I didn't ask it well. all I wanted was to check if an ID exists in the child resource or in deeper child resources of a selected parent. and the code does that.

Comment: Then you should have stated it that way in your question.